# iOS Safari App putting URL at the bottom of printed Label

Tags: javascript, css, http, safari, mendix

To start, im just the IT guy, not the coder. Just trying to figure out how to fix this is all, or get recommendations to pass along.

Currently, I am having an issue with a kiosk mode iPad (created within Intune) where it prints the URL and page number at the bottom of the label when printing visitor badge labels (on a brother printer). Is there a setting within Safari that can get rid of this? Or maybe something we can do with CSS? This is being created within Mendix, and its a fillable website where at the end it puts it all together to print a visitor badge. For context, this issue does not happen on a Windows PC or an Android Tablet. Also, since this is a Kiosk iPad, it has to use Safari. We are unable to load Chrome or Firefox onto it. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: From what I am seeing there is no way to do this with iOS Safari :(